# Displaying VLCJ in Jpanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, video, vlcj

So I'm desinging an application for offline quiz systems. Currently I'm working on the screen that is visible for the participants (only question, maybe possible answers and a media element). 
This screen contains a slide (derived from JPanel) the screen itself is a JFrame. I have to use the JPanel in another JFrame. In the JPanel of the slide is another JPanel for displaying media. I succeeded to display an image in the JPanel. But the application also has to display video and audio. I use VLCj to realize this in my application. Here is the code of the JFrame of the SlideView.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

/**
 * Created by bram on 30/03/17.
 */
public class SlideView
{

private SlidePanel slidePanel;
private JFrame frame;

public SlideView(){
    slidePanel = new SlidePanel();
    frame = new JFrame("SlideView");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Dimension dim = new Dimension();
    dim.setSize(800,450);
    frame.setMinimumSize(dim);
    frame.add(slidePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e){}
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){}
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){}
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {
            frame.add(slidePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Display the information of the slide
 * @pre slide has to be initialized
 * @pre the slideview is initialized
 * @param slide the slide that has to be displayed
 * @post the slide will be displayed
 */
public void setSlide(Slide slide)
{
    slidePanel.initializeSlide(slide);
}

/**
 * Set the slide panel
 * @param panel
 */
public void setSlidePanel(SlidePanel panel)
{
    frame.remove(slidePanel);
    slidePanel = panel;
    frame.add(slidePanel);
}

/**
 * Get the slide panel
 * @return the slide panel
 */
public SlidePanel getSlidePanel()
{
    return slidePanel;
}
}
```

And here is the code of the panel that contains the information of the slide:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;


 /**
 * Created by bram on 30/03/17.
 */
public class SlidePanel extends JPanel {

private ImageIcon bgImage;
private JLabel title, body;
private Slide slide;
private MediaView media;

public SlidePanel()
{
    bgImage = new ImageIcon("/home/bram/Documenten/School/3 BA/PSOPV/LOCAL/src/Slides/slide_background.jpg");
    this.setSize(800,450);
    createComponents();
}
/**
 * Get the media view for controlling it
 */
public MediaView getMediaView()
{
    return media;
}
/**
 * Initialize the slide
 */
public void initializeSlide(Slide slide)
{
    this.slide = slide;
    title.setText(slide.getTitle());
    body.setText(slide.getBodyText());
    media.setFile(slide.getMediaFile());
    resizeComponents();
}
@Override
/**
 * Actions that will be executed when the window is resized
 */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Draw the background image.
    g.drawImage(getResizedBackground().getImage(), 0, 0, this);
    resizeComponents();
}

/**
 * Resize the different components to the dimensions of the frame
 */
private void resizeComponents()
{
    /*Calculate the growing factor of the screen (minimum size is 800*450)*/
    float growFactor = (float) this.getWidth() / 800f;
    /*Scale the title label*/
    title.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, (int)(40*growFactor)));
    title.setBounds((int)(20 * growFactor), (int)(20*growFactor),this.getWidth(), (int)(50 * growFactor));
    /*Scale the body section*/
    body.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN,(int)(25*growFactor)));
    body.setBounds((int)(50*growFactor),(int)(0.25f*this.getHeight()),(int)((this.getWidth()-50*growFactor) * 0.5f), (int)(0.75f*this.getHeight()-20));
    /*Scale the media section*/
    media.setBounds((int)(this.getWidth()*0.5),(int)(this.getHeight()*0.30), (int)(this.getWidth() * 0.40),(int)(this.getHeight()*0.60-20));
}
/**
 * Create the title label of the slide
 */
private void createTitle()
{
    title = new JLabel("",SwingConstants.LEFT);
    title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    this.add(title);
}

/**
 * Create the body of the slide
 */
private void createBody()
{
    body = new JLabel("");
    this.add(body);
}

/**
 * Create the media section
 */
private void createMedia()
{
    media = new MediaView();
    media.setSize(100,100);
    this.add(media);
}
/**
 * Create the gui components for displaying a slide
 */
private void createComponents()
{
    createTitle();

    createBody();

    createMedia();
}
/**
 * Scale the background to the height and width of the panel
 * @return the resized background
 */
private ImageIcon getResizedBackground()
{
    Image img = bgImage.getImage();
    img = img.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    return new ImageIcon(img);
}

}
```

And finally here is the JPanel that has to display the media:

```
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.media.Media;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;


/**
 * Created by bram on 31/03/17.
 */
public class MediaView extends JPanel
{
    private MediaFile file;
    //Label for displaying a picture
    private JLabel picture;
    //Media player for video and audio
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayer;
    private int width,height;
    private static final String NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH = "lib";
/**
 * Default constructor for the mediaview class
 */
public MediaView()
{
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH);
    this.width = getWidth();
    this.height = getHeight();
}
/**
 * Add the appropriate components to the panel
 */
private void addComponents()
{
    if(file.getFileType() == MediaFile.FileType.PICTURE)
    {
        picture = new JLabel();
        this.add(picture);
    }
    if(file.getFileType() == MediaFile.FileType.VIDEO)
    {

        mediaPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(mediaPlayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mediaPlayer.setSize(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

    }

}
/**
 * Set the media file to be displayed
 * @pre the media file is initialized
 * @param file the file that has to be displayed
 */
public void setFile(MediaFile file)
{
    this.file = file;
    addComponents();
    generateView();
}
@Override
/**
 * Actions that will be executed when the window is resized
 */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(this.height != getHeight() || this.width != getWidth())
    {
        generateView();
        height = getHeight();
        width = getWidth();
    }
}
/**
 * Generate the view of the file
 */
private void generateView()
{
    if(file == null)
        return;
    if(file.getFileType() == MediaFile.FileType.PICTURE)
        generateImage();
    if(file.getFileType() == MediaFile.FileType.VIDEO)
        generateVideo();
    if(file.getFileType() == MediaFile.FileType.AUDIO)
        generateAudio();
}
/**
 * Generate the view of an audio file
 */
private void generateAudio()
{

}
/**
 * Generate the view of a video
 */
public void generateVideo()
{
    //Resize canvas
    //Load native library of VLC


}
public void playMedia()
{
    mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(file.getPath());
}
/**
 * Generate the view of an image
 */
private void generateImage()
{
    /*Get the image by path*/
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
    /*Scale the image*/
    Image img = image.getImage();
    if(image.getIconHeight() > image.getIconWidth()) {
        float growFactor = (float) this.getHeight() / (float) image.getIconHeight();
        int width = (int) (image.getIconWidth() * growFactor);
        img = img.getScaledInstance(width, this.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    } else {
        float growFactor = (float) this.getWidth() / (float) image.getIconWidth();
        int height = (int) (image.getIconHeight() * growFactor);
        img = img.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(),height,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    }
    ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(img);
    /*Set image as label icon*/
    picture.setIcon(pic);
    /*Set the bounds of the label*/
    int xCoordinate = (this.getWidth() - pic.getIconWidth())/2;
    int yCoordinate = (this.getHeight() - pic.getIconHeight())/2;
    picture.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    picture.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    picture.setBounds(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,picture.getWidth(),picture.getHeight());
}
}
```

But the video won't display (the video is a MP4 format). I tried several things (the above is the best result) does anyone can help me?

Comment: 1) *"Also it is required that.."* This is a Q&A site, not a help desk. Sort one problem this thread, and the other in a separate thread (I suggest delaying that one until this one is solved). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The code within paintComponent looks quite suspect to me. If you want code called when a component resizes, **don't** put it within paintComponent but rather put it within a ComponentListener. Also are you taking care to be sure that your code obeys Swing threading rules?

Comment: The application is single threaded. So I have to add a ComponentListener for resizing the elements?

Comment: `"The application is single threaded."` -- please explain as this suggests that you're not taking Swing threading issues into account and may be freezing your application because of this.

Comment: And read the ComponentListener API and tutorial as its use is well explained.

Comment: Be careful mixing heavy weight and light weight components, they don't always play nice together

Comment: The posted code never calls playMedia(). Also, you should re-use media player components rather than creating them each time you call setFile()/addComponents()